# how to get all tables by editing dsn file "data source file"

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

By having the next dsn file:

```
[ODBC]
DBQ=C:\\SLA.mdb
C:\\SLA.mdb
DefaultDir=C:\
Driver={Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)}
DriverId = 25
FIL=MS Access
MaxBufferSize = 2048
MaxScanRows = 8
PageTimeout = 5
SafeTransactions = 0
Threads = 3
UserCommitSync = Yes
[Microsoft Office]
DefaultTable =table1
```

how could I edit it to have my other table "table2", be shown when Microsoft Query editor opened?

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
[ODBC]
DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)
UID=admin
UserCommitSync=Yes
Threads=3
SafeTransactions=0
PageTimeout=5
MaxScanRows=8
MaxBufferSize=2048
FIL=MS Access
DriverId=25
DefaultDir=C:\
DBQ=C:\sla.mdb
```

However you can use a wizard to make these if you want to. Here is how:

1. From the run box type in "odbcad32" and hit enter. (You can also get to this from Administrative Tools>Data Sources (ODBC)).
2. Click the "File DSN" tab.
3. Click the "Add Button"
4. Select "Microsoft Access Driver".
5. Click Next.
6. Type in the path to where you want to save the DSN File (ex: C:\sla.dsn), or just click "Browse".
7. Click next.
8. Click Finish.
9. Click the "Select" button.
10. Select your Database and click "OK".
11. Click "OK" one more time to close the prompts.
12. DSN should now be ready to use.

Comment: this didn't got all tables in the query editor, it opens the add table dialog box.

Comment: That shows all the tables, and lets you select whatever you want. What happens when you just alter the default table line?